# .Net arbitratry runtime class instantion and method calling

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, runtime

I am looking for a way to do arbitrary class instantion as well as attribute assignement and possibly method calling in .Net and preferrably C#. Since *arbitrary* is too broad a word let me tell you what I am after.

Let's say I have a DLL (objects.dll) that contains:

```
public class Person
{
    // Field 
    public string name;

    // Constructor that takes no arguments. 
    public Person()
    {
        name = "unknown";
    }

    // Constructor that takes one argument. 
    public Person(string nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    }

    // Method 
    public void SetName(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

}

public class Table
{
    // Field 
    public int width;
    public int lenth;
    public int height;

    // Constructor that takes no arguments. 
    public Table()
    {
        width = 0;
        length = 0;
        height = 0
    }

    // Constructor that takes three arguments. 
    public Table(int w, int l, int h)
    {
        width = w;
        length = l;
        height = h;
    }

    // Method 
    public void SetWLH(int w, int l, int h)
    {
        width = w;
        length = l;
        height = h;
    }
}

public class Printer
{
    public Printer(){}

    public void printAPerson(Person p)
    {
        //do stuff with p
    }

    public void printATable(Table t)
    {
        // do stuff with t
    }
}
```

I want to be able to instantiate either of the classes above, set attribute values and call methods at runtime from a different program in the most generic possible. eg. lets say I hame a programm called myprog.exe, i want to be able to do the following

myprog.exe objects.dll Person name testname Printer printAPerson
where:

- objects.dll is the dll that contains all required classes
- Person is the first I will instantiate name is its attribute
- testname is the value I will assign to this attribute
- Printer is the class I will use for printing
- printAPerson is the method in the Printer class I need to call with the specified object as a parameter.

As you can see, in the best case for my use scenario, neither of the objects and classes are/will be known at compile time so I would like to be as non-casting as possible. If that is not possible I will take what I can.

I have seen this, [How to use reflection to call a method and pass parameters whose types are unknown at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830146/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-a-method-and-pass-parameters-whose-types-are-unkno), which to my limited knowledge kind of does what I want minus the casting bits or I could be mistaken.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question you link has all the answers to your questions as far as I see. What don't you understand from that post?

Comment: I explain it in my last sentence "minus the casting bits". That post specifically calls for ClassA aa = new ClassA(); instantiation at the beginning. If I could get away with that I would prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you flexible concerning your executable input format? If so, you could do what you want by having a convention. I would do this using a JSON structure like this one:

```
{
   Command : "",
   Arguments : {
      Argument1 : 0,
      Argument2 : {  }, // can be another complex object
      Argument3 : [] // an empty array maybe ...
     }
}
```

Where Command would be something like "ClassName.MethodName", Arguments will be a JSON object that each object property represents your method parameter.

In your executable, you must parse this JSON using a library (example http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and use reflection to deserialize every JSON object parameter and call your method. If you cannot get it work, please let me know I will try to make an example (if I will have time, this night because I am at work right now).

For your case you just want to print an object of type Person to the printer right? You could execute a command like this:

```
{
  Command : "Printer.PrintAPerson",
  Arguments : {
   p : { name : 'george' }
  }
}
```

If you want to rely on a standard protocol, please check the JSON-RPC protocol: http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Reflection you could use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741(v=vs.100).aspx). But this requires that the Printer class and others are changed. And you would loose intellisense and compile time checks.

```
public class Printer
{
    public Printer() { }

    public void printAPerson(dynamic p)
    {
        //do stuff with p
        Console.WriteLine("Person name: " + p.name);
    }

    public void printATable(dynamic t)
    {
        // do stuff with t
        Console.WriteLine("printATable(Table p) is called");
    }
}

public class TestDynamic
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        // To get the type by name, 
        // the full type name (namespace + type name) is needed
        Type personType = Type.GetType("StackOverflowCodes.Person");
        object personObj = Activator.CreateInstance(personType);

        // Implicit cast to dynamic
        dynamic person = personObj;
        person.SetName("Alan Turing");

        Type printerType = Type.GetType("StackOverflowCodes.Printer");
        object printerObj = Activator.CreateInstance(printerType);

        dynamic printer = printerObj;
        printer.printAPerson(personObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Muraad. I couldn't care less for intellisense in compile time checks at this point. However in your example you specifically call for person.SetName("Alan Turing"); and printer.printAPerson(personObj); and I can't afford that in my use case. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Then there is probably no way around reflection. But you would need to know the type name and method name too. Otherwise would have to search the type and method solely based on the method signature. "Iterate over all Types in the loaded assembly. Iterate over all MethodInfos of the current type. If method takes a Person and returns void you have found the (probably) right method and type". But you would have to find the Person type first... Without knowing the name of the types/methods or some other kind of convention, this could become really hairy and expensive. Greetings and good luck!